# How do I push module update in a cached production environment?

Tags: 7, caching, updating

I don't manage to update Flag module in remote server, while it worked like a charm on local environment. The stage site **is cached with Zend opcache**, Apcu, Varnish and Redis. I suspected Opcache was faultier but no way to get it work.

**The steps I did (local dev) :**

- `drush up flag -y`
- `drush cc all`. Tested flag features, OK.
- Commited & pushed files to stage on a flag branch

**The steps then on remote server :**

- `git checkout flag`
- Reset Opcache various times (thanks to this great [Opcache GUI](https://github.com/amnuts/opcache-gui))
- Saved database
- Ran `update.php`, which returned

  ```
  flag module
  7300 - Rebuild the class registry due to classes moving files.
  7301 - Rename {flag_content} table to {flagging} and {flags} table to {flag}.
  7302 - Rename database columns on the {flag} table.
  7303 - Rename database columns on the {flagging} table.
  7304 - Rename database columns on the {flag_counts} table.
  7305 - Convert flag roles to permissions.
  7306 - Convert flag view modes settings.
  ```
- Ran *Apply pending updates*, which retunred *An unrecoverable error has occurred, Ajax error, http status 200*, followed by 4 notices. These notices are known, but caused no update crash on local site.
- if I go to the "error page", I'm sent back to Review updates page.

If I try to visit dblog, I have this fatal php error : `Class 'flag_flag' not found in profiles/commons/modules/contrib/flag/flag.module on line 1948`. But if I check the remote files, I can find that class in `profiles/commons/modules/contrib/flag/includes/flag/flag_flag.inc` .

I invalidated that file namely in Opcache and invalidate full Opcache. I also checked in `varnish.vcl` that `update.php` is in the list of bypassed URL.

Then after a while, Varnish finds backend server is not responding and boom : *Error 503 Backend fetch failed*, ending restarting php5-fpm...

To be honest, I understand about nothing anymore, "*eating my hat*" or "*banging my head*" or how would you say that ? Help really welcome !

Comment: And you don't have drush access on the remote server, right?

Comment: Yes i have remote drush access

Comment: Do you use Drush? It seems like a case of a moved class file, which can sometimes cause these issues with caching, and can be solved using [Drush Registry-Rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild). If you have Memcache on the server, you should restart that too.

Comment: Some people also attribute this to APC. (Warning: old thread circa 2011) See [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1057474)

Comment: Tks I'm gonna try to rebuild registry. I restarted Redis (I don't have Memcache)

Comment: And I would also try running the updb from drush, I am not sure if op-caching applies there, so it could help.

Comment: Do you think the general workflow is correct ? I focused on built-in Zend Opcache (PHP 5.6) because I have to invalidate any file I changed. I have to know how to proceed in a cached environment before moving production there :)

Comment: @Kojo I don't think there's a correct or incorrect when it comes down to it. The only obvious thing missing from the workflow you described is putting the site into maintenance mode while running update.php. Most modules I've worked with, rarely move the important classes. Happened to me recently with AddThis though. You just have to have Registry Rebuild ready on the server's drush, in case something like this happens again.

Comment: @Beebee I thought maintenance mode was only to avoid DB being written during update. Has it got another incidence on a dev or stage site ? By correct I meant that I feel this is related to cache since I had never had this before, and I'm wondering if there's a special order in emptying caches and applying updates

Comment: Uhh no, I was speaking in terms of deploying to production. But there's nothing stopping you from doing it on dev or stage. I have a simple shell script I just execute it, and it puts the site in maintenance mode, pulls from git, clears the caches, sorts out folder/file permissions, restarts memcache and apache (with prompts) and sets maintenance mode off. Quite handy and time saver.

Comment: Sounds great, I'm afraid _we don't exactly play in the same ligue_ :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : **make extensive use of drush** !

This was quite straightforward  and successful, though I'm still not really sure if I have to empty both opcache and Varnish. This would be a huge performance hint on production server. IMO the best would be to invalidate only the changed files in opcache and voilà ?

**Steps I did (local dev) :**

- `drush up flag -y`
- `drush cc all`
- tested flag features, OK.
- commited & pushed files to stage on a flag branch

**The steps then on remote server :**

- `git checkout flag`
- `varnishadm -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret` (enter Varnish Cli)
- `varnish> ban req.http.host ~ dev.example.com && req.url ~ .` (clear varnish cache)
- reset Opcache with [Opcache GUI](https://github.com/amnuts/opcache-gui)
- `drush updb`
- `drush rr` (optional in that case since this was performed in `flag_update_7300`)

Comment: Thanks a lot to @Beebee and StefanosPetrakis for their quick help and putting me on the right direction !

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Varnish shouldn't be mandatory to empty, as it doesn't really touch PHP and MySQL until next time it talks to Apache, so it should clear by itself soon afterwards. However, I think you should instead add OPcache, APCu and Redis  cache clears (no redis experience, correct me if I'm wrong) when you make a release which changes php files/updates the db.